# How to check if a value exists in an JSON key that has an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key-value

say I have the following JSON:

```
{  
   "selfExclusionMessage":{  
      "accountId":989898,
      "expired":"false",
      "userId":"37327513",
      "products": [
        "arcade", "vegas", "ex"
        ]
   }
}
```

How can I check that a specific value is present in the products key array. For example if "arcade" value is present there. I would like to have an if statement that checks values in products array and do different things for each of the values ( arcade, vegas, ex), sometimes all three of the values will be present and sometimes only 1 or 2.

Comment: Parse the JSON to an object, then retrieve `obj.selfExclusionMessage.products.includes('arcade');`. That will return a boolean value depending on the value exists in the array or not.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to parse it with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse). The you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/includes) array prototype to check if the value is in the array.

```
const data = JSON.parse(json)
const { products } = data.selfExclusionMessage
if (products.includes('arcade')) {
 // do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional (ternary) operator with `includes()`:

```js
var jsonData = {  
   "selfExclusionMessage":{  
      "accountId":989898,
      "expired":"false",
      "userId":"37327513",
      "products": [
        "arcade", "vegas", "ex"
        ]
   }
}
function isExists(data, key, value){
  return jsonData.selfExclusionMessage[key].includes(value)? 'Exists' : 'Does not exists';
}
console.log(isExists(jsonData,'products','arcade'));
console.log(isExists(jsonData,'products','arcadexyzzzzzz'));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
let o = JSON.parse(myJSON);
for (let v of Object.values(o)) {
  if (Array.isArray(v)) return Array.includes("arcade");
  else return false;
}
```

Explanation: (1) Parse JSON into an object (2) check all object values for arrays (3) if there's an array, check to see if it has the desired value

Answer (score 0):

```js
var JSON = {
  "selfExclusionMessage": {
    "accountId": 989898,
    "expired": "false",
    "userId": "37327513",
    "products": [
      "arcade", "vegas", "ex"
    ]
  }
};
if ("products" in JSON.selfExclusionMessage) {
  console.log('Exist!');
  if (JSON.selfExclusionMessage.products.includes("vegas")) {
    console.log("includes");
  } else {
    console.log("!includes");
  }
} else {
  console.log('!Exist');
}
```

Note:- Simple way to solve this issue is to identify that object exists, then object key exists, then you check array includes value by includes method.

Answer (score -1):

```
function searchValue( json, value ) {

   return Array.isArray(json.selfExclusionMessage.products) && json.selfExclusionMessage.products.includes( value );
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.